# sidekiq on ubuntu failed to stop with upstart

Tags: upstart

I installed an upstart service for sidekiq exactly as [specified in it's wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deploying-to-Ubuntu).

That said, I have an upstart script that creates a process with:

```
# skipped other insstructions
script
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  source /home/me/.my_env
  cd /home/me
  exec bin/sidekiq -e production
EOT
end script
```

The service perfectly starts, but as one might see, sidekiq's PID is not equal to the PID that is known to `upstart`.

```
» initctl status sidekiq
# sidekiq start/running, process 16020
» ps axww|grep sidekiq
# 16181 ?        Sl     0:41 sidekiq 3.0.0 me[0 of 3 busy]
```

That configuration works for any other upstart script save for sidekiq:

```
» sudo initctl stop sidekiq
# sidekiq stop/waiting
» ps axww|grep sidekiq
# 16181 ?        Sl     0:45 sidekiq 3.0.0 me[0 of 3 busy]
```

It seems that `initctl` kills the bash process, that it treats as the job (16020), but underlying `sidekiq` continues to live:

```
» ps axww|grep  '16181\|16020'
# 16181 ?        Sl     0:45 sidekiq 3.0.0 me[0 of 3 busy]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @douglas-leeder for pointing me into right direction.

`sidekiq` is neither demonising nor forking itself (unless `-d` option is explicitly specified.) But inside my exec script I called other processes, that upstart tried to count as my general process.

`expect` option does not help here, since actual sidekiq process was, say, 6th in the chain. Even worse: specifying `expect fork` leads to upstart hangup on stopping service, while `expect daemon` hungs it up on starting it. Refer to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/421028/135490) on how to fight sidekiq hangup.

The solution I finally stuck to: one needs to define a `post-stop` section of upstart script, containing smth like:

```
post-stop script
   # ps-grep your PIDS
   # for sidekiq:
   SQ_PIDS=`ps -Ao pid,command | grep sidekiq | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /g'`
   sudo kill -USR1 $SQ_PIDS
   sleep 3
   sudo kill -9 $SQ_PIDS
   sudo rm sidekiq.pid 2>&1 >/dev/null
end script
```

The above will try to gracefully shut down sidekiq and kill it after all. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like sidekiq is deamonising or at least forking. So you need to follow http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect, either find an option to sidekiq that runs in non-daemon mode, or add an appropriate expect statement.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing me into right direction. The problem was deeper: I used complicated script inside `script` section, that created many processes during execution. Upstart seems to give up on that, so I finally added a `post-stop` section that gracefully shuts sidekiq down.